# How should I evaluate new browser languages?

Tags: javascript, compiler, browser

In these days there are many projects whose aim is to bring new languages to the browser by compiling them to JavaScript. Among the others one can mention ClojureScript, CoffeScript, Dart, haXe, Emscripten, Amber Smalltalk.

I'd like to try a few of these out, but I am not sure what I should be looking for when evaluating these languages to see if they are suitable for production.

How should I evaluate a new browser language, and what are the pitfalls I should be looking for?

Comment: Don't forget http://coffeescript.org/, IMO one of the most interessting projects of that kind

Comment: @Tom It is not actually **that** open ended. There is a new technology out there and I want to find out whether it is mature enough to use it in production. In order to do so I ask people what there experience in the usage has been. There are much more open ended questions on this site.

Comment: Please, understand that I do not want to argue over the definition of "open-ended", but I am genuinely interested in knowing which ones of these alternatives (if any) can be realistically used today in production.

Comment: @Andrea If you think the close was wrong you can flag it for moderator attention or vote to reopen. Before you do though I really suggest you read the FAQ (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Hi Andrea, you would have better luck doing some research of your own into those frameworks, picking your favorite, and posting a question which asks if [insert framework here] is a good replacement for javascript. This will keep the question focused on a single topic which can be answered by a single answer, and not lead to many answers which discuss the merits of many different frameworks.

Comment: Also I think your question would be fine with a bit of cleanup so it focuses on a single question instead asking for multiple answers/opinions/experiences. I've significantly edited your question in an attempt to make it on-topic with our site, and have flagged it for a moderator to review.

Comment: @Rachel thank you very much for improving my question!

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without you defining a clearer scope. All of the languages you listed have strengths and drawbacks. Also `I am genuinely interested in knowing which ones of these alternatives (if any) can be realistically used today in production.` and `How should I evaluate a new browser language, and what are the pitfalls I should be looking for?` are two different questions. If you're interested in the first one, then you should make that clear *in your question*.

Comment: @back2dos That comment was posted before the question was edited. The original form of the question was asking for a list of opinions/experiences related to browser-languages, and was too broad to be answered. It's been edited since then to focus on how to evaluate a browser language that compiles to Javascript

Comment: @Rachel: Thanks for clarifying that. While your edit has made the question less subjective, it has made it unanswerable as such. `How should I evaluate a new browser language?` calls for a context. As is, the question is far too general to have a meaningful answer. For example in one answer here, speculations about speed are used as a criterion, but depending on the problem domain, speed might not actually be a major concern to start with.

Comment: @back2dos I think the problem domain is simply if it is suitable for production or not. The question is asking how to determine if browser languages that compile to javascript are suitable for production, and I think [Justin's answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/140871/1130) provides a great list of questions you can use to evaluate if a browser language is suitable for production or not.

Comment: Exactly, my main point is to find out whether these tools can be used realistically at work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This list could be used to evaluate a language, technology or process.

- Does this language offer some benefit over what I currently use and trust?
- Who else is using the technology in production and how does it seem from a user stand point?
- What kind of community support does this project have? The more people using and working with something new the better your chances of getting things fixed and new features added.
- What kind of learning curve does this language have for your team? The more difficult it is to pick up the greater the returns in functionality, speed, readability or maintainability must be.
- Does this make sense for the project you are trying to complete? A great technology with only a few small advantages may not be worth the switch.
- Lastly, give it an eye test. See how it works on a small sample to see how it really works for you and what problems you need to solve.

Specific things to look for with languages that compile to JavaScript:

- Speed is a big issue with JavaScript, so testing the new language on a task vs the JavaScript you write yourself would be very helpful. You may find that the language writes faster running code than you do.
- How easy is it to debug vs using strait JavaScript? It can be an issue if the generated JavaScript is to difficult to understand when things go wrong.
- Check the overhead of using the included libraries, if everything is local it can be deceiving on how much code is being transferred to the client at every page load.

Comment: Even though this answer isn't specific to browser languages, I still think it's a very good list of questions to ask when evaluating a new language or technology. Can you improve your answer to include some specific things to look for with browser languages that compile into Javascript?

Comment: @Rachel What do you think? I am trying to write better answers, so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Sourcemaps should solve a lot of the debugging issue. They are being demo'd right now on Chrome and firefox and will allow you to write code in whatever you want (GWT, CoffeScript etc) and debug in what you wrote. I expect that they will be out in a final version in 2-4 months in several browsers and packages (GWT, CoffeeScript, ClojureScirpt etc)

Answer (score 2):

Checklist:

Potential Lose Concerns:

- How does it handle a moderately complex webApp in all browsers you typically support.
- How often do bugs get fixed?
- How are the compiler debugging options?
- What happens when you want to integrate with other dev's JS code?
- What happens when you want to explain your code to JS developers who need to work with yours?
- What happens if the community behind it walks away and JS eventually evolves beyond it leading to breakage when the JS down-compiler continues spitting out code that is no longer legal.
- What benefit is it to your career as a developer if it never gains popularity and you pissed away years of professional experience on a fad language produced by people who just don't wanna like anything that doesn't work like the languages they know better?

Hopeful Win Concerns:

- Does it help you produce faster?
- Is it an absolute joy to work with?
- Does it Make Working With the DOM easier than native JS (kind of a clunky API)
- Is it easier for dirt cheap but otherwise completely useless sweatshop devs who can barely understand the Java they pretend they know to produce viable front-end code? (hint: no, it's not)

Obviously I've got a bit of a slant here but I have no problem with other languages getting popular on the front end. But not down-compiled to JS. That's just somehow offensive to me as a JS developer. If JS does what you need it to do, bend fold and mutilate it into something that works better for your thought process. It's flexible like that. The core syntax can't be altered but you can redefine the way you personally solve problems with it very easily once you know it fairly well.

Comment: Why do you mind what other languages are compiled to? I like Javascript, but when I think of using another language, Javascript just becomes a target language. I do not feel offended that the compiler will emit unreadable code, just as I do not try to read the binary emitted by a dekstop compiler.

Comment: By the way, about your last negative point, that is actually a positive side for me. Languages like ClojureScript or Amber are based on Clojure and Smalltalk, and these will not go away any time soon. Using their in-browser counterparts allows me to learn these languages while doing my work as a frontend developer. I would have less occasions to learn, say, Clojure on the JVM

Comment: Finally, I really do not think that the people who have embraced, say, Clojurescript are people who are not willing to learn new tools. Most of them are people who were working in Java and decided to migrate to a Lisp...

Answer (score 1):

You should ignore these new languages unless they have a native VM/interpreter in at least two browsers. Only JavaScript currently complies with that criteria.

- If a language doesn't have a native VM/interpreter it's inefficient. If your writing a non-toy application then you will care about being able to optimise performance heavy parts of your application. Having to use the abstracted language and hand optimised JS is a maintenance nightmare
- If a language isn't natively supported in browsers then it's not future proof, it's a phase that will dissappear soon, (VBScript anyone?)
- All of these abstractions are leaky. Your going to have to write or debug JavaScript in the end, and I wouldn't want to do both when I can only do JavaScript.

If your willing to maintain both JavaScript and the abstracted language in your application then you might want to consider using them

Comment: So you're saying these new languages would not be appropriate for production at all until this gets implemented?

Comment: You make an interesting claim, but offer no explanation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey why you no see it's obvouis :(

Comment: I removed my downvote, but I don't buy the efficiency argument. Many of these tools (including CoffeeScript) compile down to native Javascript.  Nor do I buy the maintainability argument; most of the complexity is hidden behind an abstraction, so if you trust the tool, maintenance should be simpler, not harder.

Comment: @RobertHarvey CoffeeScript is always slower then JavaScript, if it's not, learn to write high quality JavaScript. If you think writing coffeescript and debugging/hand-tweaking JavaScript is maintainable then that's cool, I don't.

Comment: I dont see why people would use anything else tbh.. I mean seriously just learn JS, even from a personal marketability standpoint it makes sense to just learn pure beautiful JS rather than some abstraction layer that may not be around in 2 years.

Comment: Of course I want to be able to trust the compiler to produce correct and reasonably efficient code. Most of these tools produce code which is not inspectable by hand. Still, most of the desktop compilers are able to produce correct, efficient code. Why should these compilers be any less capable?

Comment: @Loktar Of course I do know Javascript quite well. Still, I would like to evaluate whether for big applications any of these compilers offer any advantage.

Comment: Chrome will support SourceMap in the very near future, which should make debugging easier.

Comment: @James and how much time do you spend debugging in chrome vs debugging in IE8 ;)

Comment: @Andrea the compilers can output correct code, that's not hard. Whether the compilers output readable or efficient code is a different matter, the answer is that the compilers produce worse JavaScript then you can write by hand, where-as C produces better machine code then you can write by hand

Comment: I tend to spend more time debugging, period, when I write Javascript without using an abstraction layer, actually. ;)

Comment: @James that just makes you a bad developer :D get better at JavaScript

Comment: Acknowledged. :-) But Javascript syntax _does_ have more fiddly bits to make typos with then most abstraction layers.

Comment: @James CoffeeScript has a ton of syntax with fiddly bits that makes it easy to make typos :\. Significantly more-so then JavaScript.

Comment: The only possible advantage is that you happen to enjoy the style of coding better. I don't know what you expect these compilers to do for you. They boil it down to JavaScript. There is nothing the new language can do that the old one couldn't other than offer a different core syntax. For all this the negatives are legion: career experience wasted on a potential fad language, you lose or at least degrade your ability to debug from the console directly, and how are JS-only teams going to integrate stuff with your post-compiled code? JS is flexible and powerful. It doesn't need a do-over.

Comment: Well, isn't this true of all languages? Turing equivalence means that you can perform in C the same stuff you can do in Haskell. You choose one language over the other based on convenience. By the way, I should make clear that I enjoy JS a lot and I am quite proficient at it. But I still would like to try out alternatives

Comment: @Andrea but the problem is that these languages don't have any advantages of value and lots of disadvantages

Comment: I see the disadvantages, but I also see potential advantages. For instance Emscripten allows to use existing C libraries - think of formats and protocols implementations. ClojureScript has the usual advantages of a Lisp and some more: macros, persistent data structures and so on. The fact that Javascript is a very enjoyable language should not be a reason to prevent the growth of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I find playing with a new technology is always going to be the best way to get to know it.

Once you have mastered the basics, you often start to try the more advanced features, or scenarios (ie. using the tool in some complex web app).

These are when you can start to find the limitations of a tool.

When this happens, I start searching SO, forums etc, to try and find ways round the issues. In these places you'll probably start to read other people's opinions and issues they have came across and it helps you get a better "feel" for the tool.

A more formal way might be trying to benchmark the tool against other solutions. Does it perform "well". (where "well" is to be defined by your system needs).

Comment: The question is asking about specific things to look for when evaluating a browser language that gets translated into Javascript, not how to learn a new technology.

Comment: @Rachel - not all tools are the same, like any new tech, the OP should play with and find it's pain points. I guess my answer is more generic than they were looking for though.

Comment: You got a downvote, because your answer is basically "try it out."  The OP is asking *how to evaluate the tool* when he does try it out.

Comment: You just got an upvote, because your answer is basically "try it out" ;)